# Singularity in Anisotrpic Rotation

Tags: shaders

I have an issue with the anisotropic (rotation) feature. I am modelling a carbon fiber texture, that should behave differently depending of incoming light and camera angle.
I use a checkerboard texture to turn adjacent squares anisotropic rotation by 0 or 90°.
Below you can find a node Wrangler output of my checkerboard.

[image: node setup and rotation in checkerboard fashion]

However, if I pass this into the anisotropic rotation, I get a singularity in the middle of the top and bottom checkerboard, it looks the bottom of a frying pan. On the sides, the texture behaves perfectly (see Images below). So my verdict is, that blender somehow mixes the rotation input with a vector rotation around local Z of my object.

[image: Anisotropic rotation as seen on the local z-up side]
[image: Anisotropic rotation after local y-side has been turned up]

Is there a way to get rid of this? (Mixing local -z into the rotation component?)

Best regards,
Carl Philipp

Comment: Isn't that how anisotropy works? If you don't like the effect why do you want to use it?

Comment: In theory, no, anisotropy just says "this material behaves differently in one direction than the other". As a user, I would expect that I can control in which direction that is and how strong the effect is.

Comment: Hello Carl :). That's just how the anisotropy shader works in Blender. Perhaps if you explain what you're after, someone will propose an alternative solution.

Comment: Create a tangent node and plug it into your anisotropy BSDF.  Play with the tangent node's settings.  You might find what you want, but at the very least, that should make it more clear to you where the rotation about local Z comes from.